# Showing zero mesh value with different color in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis

I have written a code to find values of a parameter. it shows values in a diagram with colors.  I want to find the line which separates positive and negative values of the plot.  Here is my code:

```
ListDensityPlot[datas2r, ClippingStyle -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large], FrameLabel -> {Style["Pe", Large], Style["K_B T", Large]},PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "\[Sigma]",     LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}]]
```

Comment: In order to answer the question with certainty, you'd have to provide the data set, or a representative example.

Answer (score 4):

```
ListDensityPlot[datas2r, 
 ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Thick, Large], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["Pe", Large], Style["K_B T", Large]}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
   BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "σ", 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 30}],
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshStyle -> {Thick, Red}]
```

[image]